# When I add line break (\n) in paragraph in typescript file and pass that to html is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, string

Angular Project:

**HTML file**

```html
<home-page [copy]="content"></homepage>
```

**TypeScript file**

```js
content = `Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.`;
```

Expected:

> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
>
> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

Actual:

> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `white-space: pre-line;` in your css to render line-break in text.

style.scss

```
p {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

page.html

```
<p> {{ content }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the newline to a `<br>` tag because the paragraph tag does not render newlines as line breaks (except in the source); instead it will render the newline as a space. You also need to use the [`innerHTML`](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts) directive in order for angular to render html from a property.

You will then end up with a component similar to this one:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  template: `<p [innerHTML]="content"></p>`
})
export class MyComonent {
  content = '';

  @Input()
  set copy(input: string) {
    this.content = `<p>${input.split(/\n/g).join('</p><p>')}</p>`;
  }
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-innerhtml?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: What if I am passing the content variable to a component selector. I believe I cannot use the [innerHtml] on that right?

`<my-selector [copy]="content"></my-selector>`

Comment: I would need to see the component, but if I understand, you could use `@Input() set copy(input) {this.content = input.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');}`

Comment: My bad! I just updated the question with my actual scenario.

Comment: @ShivaVatigunta I updated my answer which I think should help